# How to calculate the highest point of a given line segment after bending it?

Tags: geometry

The original 'simplified' question someone asked me was: given a straight train track, flat on the ground, of length $d = 100$ meters - how high would its highest point be after compressing the track from both sides, making it bend upwards until you're left with a length of $d = 99$ meters on the ground?

How would you calculate this?

I suggested it was basically just the Pythagorean theorem but was met with disbelief and scepticism. My reasoning: let's simplify the 3d situation to 2d - you're now left with just a line segment of length $d = 100$. Let's assume that we have 2 right triangles back to back, with a being 'the ground', b being the 'shared' edge of the 2 right triangles, and c being the hypothenuse.

Enter $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Step 1: assume a straight line segment with given length $d = 100$. So we get $a = \frac{d}{2} = 50$ (because we have 2 right triangles back to back). We can assume that $b = 0$. This would give us $c = 50$.

Step 2: we now assume the line segment was compressed and bended upwards, the length on the floor is now $d = 99$. So we get $a = \frac{d}{2} = 49,5$ and we know from step 1 that $c = 50$ thus giving us a height $b \approx 7,05$.

So the highest point would be $7,05$ meters. I believe the curved shape of the line segment is irrelevant, because all we're looking for is its highest point, which is accurately reflected through the Pythagorean theorem.

Is my reasoning solid? Are there others/better ways to calculate the answer?

Comment: In situation 1: you are assuming $a$ is the leg on the ground.  $b$ is the height. And $c$ is the hypotenuse.  If you let $a=50$ and $b=0$ then the "triangle" is just the flat line and $c = a$ and the heighest point is $0$.  You haven't bent the track at all.  If you want to do it this way, you need $a = \frac {99}2$, the track on the ground, and $c$ the hypotenuse is have the origninal lenghth so $c=\frac {100}2$.  So to find the height you must solve for $b$.  $(\frac {99}2)^2 + b^2 =(\frac {100}2)^2$. Which is situation 2. Situation 1 is just nonsense and *not* the problem at all.

Comment: Note the problem is an elipse with loci at $(-44.5,0)$ and $(0, 44.5)$ and the the sum of the distances from loci to point plus distance for other loci to point is $r_1 + r_2 = 100$.  Generalize that.

Comment: Your reasoning is a first approximation, I expect the real height to be slitghtly smaller. For instance, if you suppose the track to bend in a circular shape, then you get $b\approx 6.1$ meters.

Comment: Are you bending of folding? In case of bending, do you get a circle, a parabola or something else? ...?